# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile как исправить

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть **javafx** проект, я сделал `jar` файл так: в структуре проекта выбрал `Artifacts`->`нажал плюс`->`JAR`->`from modules with dependencies`. Далее указал где у меня находится Main класс. После этого забилдил `jar` файл. Нажимаю я на него а там ошибка следующая: `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile` . Как исправить?

**Файл manifest.mf**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Graphics
```

**Структура проекта:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем `idea` в не правильный каталог генерирует `Manifest` файл. Нужно его перекинуть в `resources`

Answer (score 1):

Если возникает данная ошибка, то необходимо:

1. Перенести папку `META-INF` с файлом `MANIFEST.INF` в папку `resources`
2. Нажать `Build Project (Ctrl+F9)`
3. После построения нажать `Run (Ctrl+F10)`
4. Проверить на правильность выполнения Вашего кода (в большинстве случаев ошибка пропадает)