# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile

Tags: java, gradle, jar

Есть проект gradle. Я его собрал в артефакт, в свойствах указал, что это запускаемый файл, но при попытке запустить в терминале пишется следующее: `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile unnamed.jar`. Что делаю не так?

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Frames.MainForm
```

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Оно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836820/error-invalid-or-corrupt-jarfile-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Видел. Переносил, толку ноль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закинул папку META-INF вручную в jar файл с помощью архиватора.